# How to reuse methods on jquery plugin creation

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have created a jquery plugin, which contains the below code.

```
$.fn.funcname = function(){

var defaults = {};

// extend code

$(this).click(function(){       

    // using this keyword inside  this function.
    $(this)...... 



})

}
```

I want to use this this.click event on dom loads also and click events also. How can we reuse?

Comment: What would `this` be when there's no click event?

Comment: it is a checkbox. We need to check whether that is clicked or not, on load of dom also and i have to use that function on click event also.

Comment: wait, you `want to use "this.click" event`... you mean you want to click it? or just check if the checkbox's PROPERTY = checked?

Comment: 1. Click check box - call function,
2. Onload Dom - check checkbox clicked or not - call the same function.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger events of the element you have executed the anonymous function on..

```
$('#myDiv').funcname();

$('#myDiv').trigger('click'); // will fire the funcname click event handler.
```